# Using Apache CXF to set up a Soap endpoint - how to get message as simple XML?

Tags: xml, soap, cxf

I am trying to set up a simple SOAP endpoint that can take the SOAP request and put the body on a camel route as XML without making it into a POJO or doing any other conversions.   Everything I have read indicates that PAYLOAD will bring in the payload as a string, but it is actually an

```
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload
```

Is there some syntax that will simply bring in a soap body as XML into a camel route?

```java
    from("cxf:?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
    .to("testBean");
```

```java
@Handler
public void testThis(Exchange exchange, Message message) {
    System.out.println("here I am");
    String thisBody = message.getBody(String.class);
    System.out.println(thisBody);
}
```

```
Error during type conversion from type: 
java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String with value    
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload@3138546a 
due java.lang.IllegalStateException: StAXSource(XMLStreamReader) with 
XMLStreamReadernot in XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT or     
XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT state
```

Note that exchange.getIn().getBody() does the same thing - brings in a CfxPayload which I cannot convert to a string without marshal / unmarshal.  I do not want this to be tied to some object, I really just want the XML string. -

My architecture:
embedded Tomcat
Camel 2.16 
Spring 4.1.8